# Is there a way to easily serialize form input into xml or yaml for database storage?

Tags: xml, serialization, asp-classic, vbscript, yaml

I am dealing with an old app in asp classic vbscript. I'd like to store the input of a form in a database text field as the form fields are a subject to frequent change and I don't feel like normalizing the old database.

Any solutions for serialization in vbscript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and use the Form collection.

Request.Form

http://www.w3schools.com/ASP/showasp.asp?filename=demo_simpleform1

ProTip - parse data into xml format. Then you have many more options for using the data.

Comment: What is your recommendation of a classic ASP or JScript library that will dump to XML and then parse XML? That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: This should point you in the right direction and provide some sample script:
http://www.asp101.com/articles/michael/htmlxml/

Comment: Thank you, this is the best from all I've seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this json implementation in jscript for asp classic.

http://tforster.wik.is/ASP_Classic_Practices_For_The_21st_Century/JSON4ASP